# Connecting to MSMQ from remote machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, msmq

I'm trying to connect to MSMQ running on an AWS EC2 instance using the following connection :

```
MessageQueue = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=TCP:xx.xxx.xx.xxx\\private$\\TestQueue");
```

I've enabled all the appropriate traffic with the AWS security group and windows firewall. The error I'm getting is "Remote computer is not available."

Is MSMQ meant to work between windows machines which are not in the same domain, and without having to use HTTP ?

I'm including this netstat trace because it looks like MSMQ service is not listening on the public interface, but not sure how to fix this if it is the issue.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -abno | findstr 1801
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1801           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4184
  TCP    [::]:1801              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4184
```

Comment: Are you sending to, or receiving from, the queue? If 'receiving' then you're trying to use the RPC protocol which requires more work than sending over HTTP.

Comment: MSMQ works fine without domains but you may need to make some configuration and permission changes.